# How do I get AST as string using libclang?

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, libclang

I need to transverse AST using libclang.
All solutions I have found tell me to dump the AST in a .ast file and then create translationUnit with that file for transversing.

It would be great to be able to do the following:
Generate AST for some code programmatically and then use CXUnsavedFile to create translationUnit with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid depending on AST dumped inside a file,
clang_parseTranslationUnit can be used as follows

```
CXTranslationUnit unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(
CXIndex index,
"path to file with code", nullptr, 0,
nullptr, 0,
CXTranslationUnit_None);
```